angular ng add @angular/ssr error Cannot find module '@inquirer/prompts'
I have installed Angular 19.0.

I want to install Server Side rendering package
ng add @angular/ssr

I have this error
Cannot find module '@inquirer/prompts'
Require stack:
- C:\directory\node_modules\@schematics\angular\ssr\index.js

I run npm update
But I have the same error.
How can I fix it?
Thanks

I could not reproduce your issue.
It looks like a dependency is missing somehow. I would delete the lock file and the node_modules directory, and install the dependencies from scratch.
It should fix your issue.
